# problem with multiple animation at the same time

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, animation, uiimageview

here is my code :

```
-(void) createNewImage {
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
 [imageViewArray addObject:imageView];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
}

-(void)moveTheImage{
for(int i=0; i< [imageViewArray count];i++){
 UIImageView *imageView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
}
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onTimer2)];
[displayLink setFrameInterval:1];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
```

So what I want to do is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD3MTTPaK98.
But my problem is that after  imageView is created(createNewImage) it stops after 4 seconds (maybe due to the timer).I want that imageView continue moving while new imageView are created. How can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Where is your `onTimer` code?

Comment: no i change onTimer with createNEwImage and onTimer2 with moveTheImage

Comment: I was asking what code you have in your `onTimer` function.

Comment: onTimer is createNew Image . it was an error

Answer (score 1):

Instead, keep a reference to the point you want all your images to move too. Using an NSTimer and moving all the images yourself in the timer will eventually slow down your app a lot (I know from experience). Use UIView animation blocks, and just tell it to move to the point when you create it.

```
-(void) createNewImage {
   UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
   imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
   [imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];

   //Move to the centerPoint
   [self moveTheImage:imageView];

   [imageViewArray addObject:imageView];
   [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
}

-(void)moveTheImage:(UIImageView *)imageView {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                    animations:^{
                       [imageView setCenter:centerPoint];
                    }];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   //IDK what all that other code was

   centerPoint = self.view.center;
}
```

EDIT: Finding the UIImage during animation

You need to reference the presentation layer of the UIImageView to find its position during an animation

```
UIImageView *image = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:0];
CGRect currentFrame = [[[image layer] presentationLayer] frame];

for(UIImageView *otherImage in imageViewArray) {

   CGRect objectFrame = [[[otherImage layer] presentationLayer] frame];

   if(CGRectIntersectsRect(currentFrame, objectFrame)) {
       NSLog(@"OMG, image: %@ intersects object: %@", image, otherImage);
   }
}
```

Comment: I us NSTimer because with UIView animation blocks it's not possible to use CGRectIntersects for collision, so the system just know the startpoint and the endpoint. That is why I don't use UIView animation

Comment: "I us NSTimer because with UIView animation blocks it's not possible to use CGRectIntersects for collision, so the system just know the startpoint and the endpoint." This isn't true. What you are attempting to say is you don't know where the pic is during the animation. You use the presentation layer of the UIView to figure this position out, look at the update code I provided.